# EntityFramework pass user who performed query to MSSQL

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a MSSQL database and an ASP.NET MVC Core WebApi project with EntityFramework Core.

I have custom tables called Users, and BlogPosts.
I want to update BlogPosts column "ModifiedById" everytime it is updated by Id from the Users table.

I thinking of using SQL Trigger for such operation, but I cannot find a way to pass user id with every query. The downside is that I would need one trigger per table.

Is there a better solution?

[edit] Yes there is :) As proposed, the best option is to override SaveChanges() method of the DbContext.

regards,
p.

Comment: That would only work if you are using AD to connect to the sql server instance, you could then insert their SQL Server associated ID or their AD username. That would then be available in the trigger as you cannot pass information to a trigger.

Comment: Are you searching CURRENT_USER ? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176050.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @tym32167, CURRENT_USER or USER_NAME(USER_ID()) returns the user from Connection string.

I need to have a user from my table Users, which means I need to put him somewhere in my DbContext. But where?

Comment: @Igor, that's not an option. I would like to implement a simple message board/blog site.

Comment: Then a trigger is obviously not the correct choice. In the EF DbContext you can override the `SaveChanges` method. You can then iterate over everything that is about to be saved to the data store. Using an interface like `IModifiedByUser` you can find all instances that were changed and implement that interface, then assign the user id to the property of the interface. This is the best generic approach. Alternatively do it in your controller per action the same way you do for anything else you set before you update.

Comment: @Igor, the interface seems to be the best choice since it can be generic oposed to triggers which need to be created per table.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I usually do it via inheritance and overriding SaveChanges() - this works with Code First and saves having to have the audited fields manually added to each class.

```
public abstract class TrackedEntity
{
    public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public DateTime ModifiedDate { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}


public class SomeOtherClass : TrackedEntity
{
     // Class specific properties here
}
```

and then in your DbContext

```
private User _loggedOnUser

    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var timestamp = DateTime.Now;

        // First look at new items these need created date adding
        var addedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added).Select(x => x.Entity);

        foreach (var addition in addedEntities)
        {
            var entity = addition as TrackedEntity;

            if (entity != null)
            {
                entity.CreatedDate = timestamp;
                entity.ModifiedDate = timestamp;
                entity.ModifiedBy = _loggedOnUser;
            }
        }

        // Next look at modified entries
        var modifiedEntities = ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified || x.State == EntityState.Deleted);

        foreach (var update in modifiedEntities)
        {
            // Only check tracked entities if modified
            if (update.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
                var tracked = update.Entity as TrackedEntity;

                if (tracked != null)
                {
                    tracked.ModifiedDate = timestamp;
                    tracked.ModifiedBy = _loggedOnUser;
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

and to get the user

```
    private void GetUser()
    {

        string user = string.Empty;

        // if we have an http context, lets try it first
        if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current != null)
        {
            if (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity != null && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
                user = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
        }

        if (user == null)
            user = System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal.Identity.Name;

        _loggedOnUser = this.Users.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Username == user);
    }
```

Comment: It would be better / more extensible if you changed `class TrackedEntity` to `interface ITrackedEntity`. This allows your types to be decorated and will not restrict it to a base type.

Comment: @Igor It depends on your use case. You're not wrong, but I don't think it is automatically "better"

Comment: Is there a particular reason to avoid `IEnumerable.OfType<T>()` for the casting in `SaveChanges()`? No judgement, just curious :)

Comment: I would go with the interface over a base class, but other than that it makes sense. I'm having IEntity interface already for some generic actions.

I'm also not using code first approach

Comment: @Gusdor No specific reason. I have read elsewhere that `is` is one of the most efficient ways of casting, but I am going to take a look at `IEnumerable.OfType<T>()` now

Comment: @KerPi The code should be almost identical using an interface

Comment: I disagree, an interface would be better. An inheriting from an abstract class is great when you want to extend it or make use of existing behavior. In this case there is no behavior or code you, only a set of properties with no behavioral code. By using an abstract class anyways you have now limited the entities themselves as they could not inherit from any other base class in the future. So it is a better design to use an interface instead.

Comment: True in general, but these are data classes for mapping to a database table. They tend not to have any functionality over and above accessors/mutators to inherit. Specifically with Code First If I implement the interface I have to copy and paste those properties into every class. It's not a deal breaker, but if I am 95% sure that I won't need a different base entity (and that base entity not to be change tracked as well and thus able to inherit from my TrackedEntity) then I don't see it as a problem

Comment: @ste-fu, if you have N:N relationship you either need to add ModifiedOn/By and use the base class, or don't use the base class.
In my example I added also ModifiedBy and ModifiedOn which are not used in every class/table. I cna think of other situations, where you would want to add other properties that shouldn't be tied to a base class.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks @Igor and @ste-fu.

As suggested I've overriden SaveChanges as follows:

```
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var timeStamp = DateTime.UtcNow;
        var userId = this.GetAuthenticatedUser();

        this.HandleAddedEntities(userId, timeStamp);
        this.HandleModifiedEntities(userId, timeStamp);

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
    private void HandleAddedEntities(Guid userId, DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                        .Where(x => x.Entity is IAddedEntity && 
                                    x.State == EntityState.Added)
                        .Select(x => x.Entity as IAddedEntity);

        foreach (var e in entities)
        {
            e.CreatedById = userId;
            e.CreatedOn = timeStamp;
        }
    }

    private void HandleModifiedEntities(Guid userId, DateTime timeStamp)
    {
        var entities = ChangeTracker.Entries()
                         .Where(x => x.Entity is IModifiedEntity && 
                                     (x.State == EntityState.Added || 
                                      x.State == EntityState.Modified))
                         .Select(x => x.Entity as IModifiedEntity);

        foreach (var e in entities)
        {
            e.ModifiedById = userId;
            e.ModifiedOn = timeStamp;
        }
    }
```

As noted in the comments I used interfaces because that way I am open to other "generic triggers" should the need arise.

Thanks guys for extra quick responses.

Comment: Glad it worked for you. Please also consider accepting an answer (see [How to accept SO answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235)). I would recommend @ste-fu's answer as that is the one that was most helpful getting you to where you needed to go.

Comment: I did, but because of my rank it wasn't visible.

Comment: There are 2 options: upvote/downvote (what you just did). That was not yet available to you (when below 15 pts). You use the arrows to do this, you can upvote as many answers on your question (or others) as you see fit. Marking an answer though is done only by the asker of the question (you in this case) using the Checkbox next to the answer, only 1 answer can be marked as "the answer".

Answer (score 0):

If you're using WebMatrix:

```
using WebMatrix.WebData;
//...
BlogPost bp = new BlogPost()
{
    // other properties
    ModifiedById = WebSecurity.CurrentUserId,
}
```